# $m'$-group being cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Given a group $G=\mathbb{Z}_m\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_n$ with $m,n$ coprime. Should every subgroup of $G$ that has order coprime to $m$ be cyclic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because if $H$ is such a subgroup, then by Lagrange $H \cap \Bbb{Z}_{m} = \{ e \}$, so that $H$ is isomorphic to its image under the homomorphism
$$
G \to \Bbb{Z}_{n}
$$
that has $\Bbb{Z}_{m}$ as kernel. So $H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the cyclic group $\Bbb{Z}_{n}$, and as such $H$ is cyclic.

Comment: Can we say that this $H$ is unique up to isomorphism? Thanks

Comment: @Babak.S, if it is cyclic, then it is automatically unique.

Comment: @BabakS., there are as many isomorphism types for $H$ as there are distinct subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}_{n}$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Yes, I got it. I see that. Thanks (+1)

Comment: @BabakS., we can say that the isomorphism type of $H$ is determined by its order.

Comment: @BabakS., you're welcome, and nice to see you :-)

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, thank you for your quick response and nice to see you again also!